# Use array_merge_recursive for unknown number of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP script where I get a random number of arrays nested inside an array and need to merge them using `array_merge_recursive`.  Given the number of nested arrays is always variable, is there a way to use `array_merge_recursive` in this scenario? I am looking to do something to the effect of the following in a dynamic manner.

```
array_merge_recursive($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2], etc);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func_array()` and each element (array) of `$arr` will be passed as individual arguments:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arr);
```

You can also use argument unpacking `...` which will *unpack* each element of `$arr` into individual arguments:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive(...$arr);
```